# After maunual apt-get upgrade, Software Updater still wants me to update

Tags: 16.04, apt, update-manager

I run Xubuntu Xenial, did a manual `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. After that the Software Updater still pops up and ask me to install 68 MB of Ubuntu base updates. Why did the manual upgrade missed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man apt-get`:

> `upgrade` is used to install the newest versions of all packages
>              currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in
>              `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Packages currently installed with new
>              versions available are retrieved and upgraded; *under no
>              circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages
>              not already installed retrieved and installed*. New versions of
>              currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without
>              changing the install status of another package will be left at
>              their current version. An update must be performed first so that
>              apt-get knows that new versions of packages are available.

TL;DR: Some of the upgrades require the installation of new packages, and `apt-get upgrade` won't do that. You may consider `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Or `apt upgrade`.